# JS Date Object value of month is wrong

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I used Date object but value of getMonth is wrong.

```
$(document).on("click", "#clossing", function()
      {

        var today= new Date();
        console.log(today);
        var year=today.getFullYear();
        var month=today.getMonth();
        var date=today.getDate();
        var filename=year+"/"+month+"/"+date+".txt";
        console.log(month);

        saveToFile_Chrome(filename,"hello");

      });
```

Time is 2020-06-17 5:30 pm  but var month is 5

Here is console.log(today):Wed Jun 17 2020 17:30:43 GMT-0400

Why is it differnt?

Comment: Oh month is starting from 0 :) check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it for the first time now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date object return a zero based month, is working fine! just add +1 to month variable.

```js
var today= new Date();
        console.log(today);
        var year=today.getFullYear();
        var month=today.getMonth() + 1;
        var date=today.getDate();
        var filename=year+"/"+month+"/"+date+".txt";
        console.log(month);
```

Comment: Wow !  I knew it for the first time now. Thank you!